# Django Implement Search by location of google maps

Tags: django, gis, geodjango

I am trying to implement a search system in my Django apps.

For example, I have many service sellers person in a city.

When user Search by its location that will google map autosuggest in my form search field. After users/clients click on choose a location, they will get all the salesperson location nearby the location they are expecting.

The search system will look like these websites:

```
https://www.foodpanda.com.bd/
https://www.justdial.com/
https://www.hungrynaki.com/
```

I am not getting should I use `GeoDjango` or not. I know I need to use google API but I am not getting how to store the location data in my database. I see `GeoDjango` solves this problem very well, yet I am confused if `GeoDjango` is a good fit for my project.

Your suggestion much appreciated,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both is possible. Quite hard to tell if GeoDjango ist the best fit for you. To answer your question how to store loaction data in your database without using GeoDjango:

Just create a new Model with all the Address details you need. Maybe it is something like this:

```
class Location(models.Model):
    latitude = models.FloatField(null=True, default=None, verbose_name="location latitude")
    longitude = models.FloatField(null=True, default=None, verbose_name="location longitude")
    street = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name="street")
    zip_code = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name="zip code")
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name="city")
    country = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name="country")
```

As a third option you could use:
https://github.com/caioariede/django-location-field